# Erro em query INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Sou nova usando o Oracle SQL Developer e estou tentando fazer com a query corra mas esta surgindo erro, ver foto.[image: erro]

Comment: Veja se o ID de sua tabela está com auto_increment, caso não esteja você vai sempre precisar adicionar o ID no insert.

Comment: cido18 coloquei o ID e nao deu

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro é necessário verificar se já existe a SEQUENCE da tabela PERSON. É interessante usar uma SEQUENCE para gerar os valores para chave primária.

> Use a instrução CREATE SEQUENCE para criar uma seqüência, que é um objeto de banco de dados do qual vários usuários podem gerar inteiros únicos. Você pode usar seqüências para gerar automaticamente valores de chave primária. [[SQL Language Reference, 2016](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084.pdf), 1.173 p.]
>
> Quando um número de sequência é gerado, a seqüência é incrementada, independentemente da transação se comprometer ou reverter. Se dois usuários simultaneamente incrementarem a mesma seqüência, os números de seqüência que cada usuário adquire podem ter lacunas, porque os números de seqüência estão sendo gerados pelo outro usuário. Um usuário nunca pode adquirir o número de seqüência gerado por outro usuário. Depois de um valor de sequência ser gerado por um usuário, esse usuário pode continuar a acessar esse valor independentemente de a sequência ser incrementada por outro usuário. [[SQL Language Reference, 2016](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084.pdf), 1.173 p.]

```
CREATE SEQUENCE person_seq 
    START WITH 1000 
    INCREMENT BY 2
    NOCACHE
    NOCYCLE;
```

Então, você pode testar:

```
SELECT person_seq.nextval FROM DUAL;
```

Agora sim você pode realizar o inserte na tabela:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (PERSON_ID, PERSON_NAME, AGE)
    VALUES (person_seq.nextval,'Diana','28');
```

<sub>**NOTA**: Importante entender que existem muitas maneiras de fazer isso. Criar uma trigger e vincular a SEQUENCE com as ações de INSERT e/ou UPDATE da tabela.</sub>

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[SQL Language Reference, 2016], Copyright © 1996, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates, **[Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084.pdf)**: 11g Release 2 (11.2). Disponível em: < https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084.pdf >. Acesso em 25 Nov. 2017</sub>
<sub>[Java Developer’s Guide, 2009], Copyright © 1996, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates, **[Oracle Database Java Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225.pdf)**: , 11g Release 1 (11.1) B31225-05. Disponível em: < https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225.pdf >. Acesso em 25 Nov. 2017</sub>